# React div background in react not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a prop being injected in my component called headerImage. I know it's there because when I place it in the HTML of the component like so:

```
<h1>Hello, {headerImage}</h1>
```

It renders correctl URI of the image in the above snippet.

However when I place it in my div background style, it won't render for whatever reason:

```
<div
                className="hide-on-mobile center-image"
                style={{
                  backgroundImage: `url({headerImage})`,
                  backgroundSize: "cover",
                  backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
                  backgroundPosition: "right",
                  width: "100%",
                  height: "auto",
                }}
              ></div>
```

I see it in the developer tools not being properly evaluated:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You need to quote more than just the headerImage.  It's kind of crazy syntax, so let me look that up before I provide you with the wrong stuff... lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may just be missing a `$` evaluation before you try and pass through `${headerImage}`.

```html
<div className="hide-on-mobile center-image"
  style={{
    backgroundImage: `url(${headerImage})`,
    backgroundSize: "cover",
    backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
    backgroundPosition: "right",
    width: "100%",
    height: "auto",
  }}
></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, to nest variables within an attribute, you must quote the whole attribute, then inject an interpreted variable in to that using the `${}` notation.

This is the same technique that you would use if you need to inject more than one class names.  Since that is an simpler example, let me share that first, which may make more sense due to the simplicity and that it's using two variables instead of just one, then I'll expand it to your attribute.

So to start off with, I have a css source tied to my component.  I'm including this so you know where "styles" is defined.
`import styles from './PageHeader.module.css';`

Then within my component, where I use the two class names from "styles":

```html
<span className={`${styles.left} ${styles.headerlink}`}>
```

Notice `className={}` has the back-tick quote within the `{}`.

So then to extend to your attribute:

```html
  className="hide-on-mobile center-image"
      style={`
          backgroundImage: "url(${headerImage})",
          backgroundSize: "cover",
          backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
          backgroundPosition: "right",
          width: "100%",
          height: "auto"
       `}
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Yes, I think @Marco's solution is a more graceful. But this is another way that could be used.